# jQuery changing plugin property

Tags: jquery, qtip

I want to show tooltip using [qtip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).
I show tooltip on cells of a table.
 qtip content comes form a Div.
I am changin Div content on 'mouseenter' event of table cells.
but because of Div is empty on document ready all tooltips are empty.
How can I fix it? Should I change plugin property on mouseenter event ? or using callback functions...?
Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
    //Refreshing Div content
    $(".NegsoUser").bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var UserName = $(this).text();
        var fileName = '~/UI/Controls/SecurityManagement/Ajax/UserInormation.ascx';
        var props = [{ 'Key': 'UserName', 'Value': UserName}];
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ path: fileName, properties: props });
        $("#NegsoUserMoreInfo").advloaduc({
            ucMethodJsonParams: jsonText
        });
    });

    $(".NegsoUser").qtip(
   {
   content: $("#NegsoUserMoreInfo").html()

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qtip` has the [`updateContent`](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#updateContent) method, which you could use when you're updating the content of the div. I don't know what this `advloaduc` plug-in is that you're using to update the `div`, but it looks like it does an ajax call; so you'd want to call `updateContent` in its success callback.

Comment: Yes you are right advloaduc does an ajax call.
would you please give me a short example that how updateContent works?

Comment: Like this ? 
I can't find a sample with updateContent
$(".NegsoUser").qtip("updateContent", "test");

Comment: @shaahin: That's the *usual* way you'd call a jQuery plug-in method, but it appears that qTip uses its own different method instead; [more here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#access). You pass in an object for the `api` option of `qtip` which has an `onRender` function on it, then call `updateContent` on `this` within `onRender`. *sigh* Perhaps qTip is an old plug-in before de facto standards for this stuff emerged.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working example of a dynamic tooltip using qtip:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/translation

Hope this helps. Cheers